# How to create rounded clipping background in css

Tags: css

I have a text which comes from API and displayed in multiple lines. I wanted to create the clipping backgound around the text as shown in attached image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/75J60.png

I tried multiple ways but could not achieve the desired output.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The convex round corners could be achieved with `box-decoration-break`, applied to an inline element containing the text. But the concave ones can't be achieved this way - those would not be "rounded corners" of your actual content to begin with, but would have to be "added" in those positions somehow. You can't use pseudo elements here, if the whole text is inside just one element; you would have to break it into separate elements, one per line - but then it will become quite "static", you would need a JS solution if you wanted to make that dynamic so that it can adapt to different widths.

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error with some `filter` magic, I've made something smimilar. However it's quite hard to adjust the color due to the use of `contrast`.

But it could be a starting point for you:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  --spread: 12px;
  --roundiness: 8px;

  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: var(--spread);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  padding: calc(var(--spread) * 2) var(--spread);
}

.shadow-container {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  filter: blur(var(--roundiness)) contrast(40);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.shadow {
  background-color: #000;
  color: green;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  padding: var(--spread);
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.actual {
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container shadow-container">
    <span class="text shadow">Lorem, ipsum dolorsit<br>ametconsectetur adipisicing<br> elit.<br>Eos adipisci<br> autem.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text actual">Lorem, ipsum dolorsit<br>ametconsectetur adipisicing<br> elit.<br>Eos adipisci<br> autem.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```